# How to Correct the Polymorphism

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I have the following code.

```
#include <iostream>

class Base1
{
public:

  void print(){std::cout<<"Printing Base1\n";}
};


class Derived1: public Base1
{
public:
  void print_1(){std::cout<<"Printing Derived1 \n";}
};



class Base2
{
public:
  void myFunction1( Base1& b1)
  {
    myFunction2(b1);

  }

  virtual void myFunction2( Base1& b1)
  {
    b1.print();
  }
};

class Derived2: public Base2
{
public:
  void myFunction2( Derived1& d1)
  {
    d1.print_1();
  }
};





int main()
{
  Base1 b1;
  Derived1 d1;
  Base2 b2;
  Derived2 d2;
  b2.myFunction1(b1);
  d2.myFunction1(d1);
  return 0;
}
```

It results in the following output:

```
Printing Base1
Printing Base1
```

I thought of getting the following output

```
Printing Base1
Printing Derived1
```

One of the ways to get the desired output is to do the following.

```
class Derived2: public Base2
    {
    public:
      void myFunction2( Base1& b1)
      {
        Derived1* d1 = static_cast<Derived1*> (&b1);
        d1.print_1();
      }
    };
```

I would like to allow Derived2 to only deal with Derived1 and not with Base1. Otherwise, Some user may call Derived2::myFunction2 with Base1 object which can crash the program in such cases.

Is there a good solution?

Comment: make print virtual in Base1

Comment: Why can't you simply change the parameter from `Base1&` to `Derived1&`, if you only want to deal with `Derived1`?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, Thanks for the comment. There was a typo. Class Derived function has a different function "print_1". I have corrected the question.

Comment: I retracted my vote to close after seeing the edit.

Comment: @VikashKesarwani Thanks for the comment. There was a typo. Class Derived function has a different function "print_1". I have corrected the question.

Comment: "I would like to allow Derived2 to only deal with Derived1 and not with Base1". A method signature is a contract. You added a method, you have signed a contract. Now you *and all your ancestors* have to honour it. Either don't have a method that accepts a Base1, or be prepared to deal with Base1. Simple!

Answer (score 1):

`myFunction2()` in `Derived2` does not override `myFunction2()` in `Base2`.

A virtual function gets overridden only if its signature matches, exactly. The function in this derived class takes a different parameter than the one in the base class. Hence, it does not override.

You have to make it override, as your first step.

```
class Derived2: public Base2
{
public:
  void myFunction2( Base1& d1) override;
};
```

Now it's overridden. If you explicitly specified the `override` qualifier, as I did here, your compiler would've yelled at you already.

Now, your goal is to have whatever `myFunction2` does, only have it take in effect for `Derived1` class, and for all other `Base1` classes, use what the superclass does.

Ok. This will require a little bit more work, and it will be slightly difficult to follow along. What needs to happen is another virtual inheritance, in `Base1` this time:

```
class Derived2: public Base2
{
public:
  void myFunction2( Base1& d1) override
  {
      d1.print_from_Derived2( *this );
  }
};
```

Now, you need to define `Base1::printDerived2()`, which will invoke `print()`, which is what should happen in this case, according to your question:

```
class Base1
{
public:
       virtual void print_from_Derived2( Derived2 &)
       {
              print();
       }
};
```

And now, override it in `Derived1` in order to put the last piece of the puzzle together:

```
class Derived1 : public Base1
{
public:
       void print_from_Derived2( Derived2 &) override
       {
              // Do whatever print() from Derived2 needs to do, for
              // this object, which is Derived1.
       }
};
```

And here, you will do whatever needs to be done for `Derived2` to print only `Derived1`. It's a bit of a circuitous route, but you finally reached the place where both actors are `Derived1` and `Derived2`, without breaking any rules, and without any ugly casts.

You will need to do a bunch of forward declarations here, in order to stitch together all of these moving pieces. My examples are just brief simplifications, and they obviously have mutual references to each one, and will have to be broken apart into separate declarations and definitions, with appropriate forward declarations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, there was a typo. Class Derived function has a different function "print_1". I have corrected the question.

Comment: That's fine. The names of the functions really don't matter. The principle, and the solution, is the same.